# Add a where clause to context.Set<T> in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

in aspnet core EntityFrameworkCore I'm developing a generic class to handle db operations and I have a Read() method that retrieves data from db like this:

```
            using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var result = await context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
                return result;
            }
```

Now I wold like to filter the data adding a where or something similiar, in order to be able to filter one or more Entitiy's properties, for exeample:

TypeId = 2

How can I get this?

Comment: have you used the `.Where(...)` extension method for `IQueryable`?

Comment: *I'm developing a generic class to handle db operations* - I often wonder why people do this

Comment: thank you @DanielA.White I didn't get your point, where should I use the .where() ? And I would like to send the query with where to the db and not filtering received data after obteining the whole table from the db. Thanks again

Comment: context.Set<T> is used for add,update,delete.  create a linq query using dbcontext to extract your where iqueryable or ienumerable data.

Comment: Could you elaborate please what the problem with that? @CaiusJard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned in the comments, you need to use [the `Where` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where).

For example:

```
public async Task<List<T>> Read(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
{
    using (MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var result = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
        if (filter != null) result = result.Where(filter);
        return await result.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Entity Framework will convert the filter to a SQL query and perform the filtering in the database, rather than loading the entire set into memory before filtering it.

**NB:** This is a rather leaky abstraction. If you use any constructs in your filter parameter which aren't supported by Entity Framework, then you will get an exception at runtime.